# django overwrite db entries

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-forms

I've a MySQL db table like this:

```
id, field1, field2, field3
```

id is the primary key and auto increment

I'm writing a button that allows user to update field1, however, it ends up overwriting all entries that share the same field2, here's my code to do the update in views.py:

```
my_model = MyModel.objects.get(id=id)
my_model.field1= request.POST.get('new_field1_value')
my_model.save()
```

So, I used the primary key to get the only entry from my db and then do the update, however, it's overwriting all entries in my db that share the same value of field2, I'm very confused, any help is really appreicated!

Comment: That wouldn't happen with the code you have shown. Please show the real model definition and view code.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for poking me, while editing my model definition to post, I saw that I've also accidentally set field2 as my primary key, once I removed that in my model, overwriting bug is gone, thanks a lot!